# How to Split a Single Digit in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to know if there is a way in which I can split a single digit when there is no delimiter.
For example: Cell A1 contains 940 and I want to convert it into 9:40 AM.

[image]

Comment: And for other cell? 1817 will be `6:17 PM`?

Comment: You can use `=IFERROR(INDEX(--REPLACE(A2:A,LEN(A2:A)-1,0,":")),"")` and choose a numberformat of your liking.

Answer (score 1):

Try below formula. This will require to format your cell as time.

```
=TIME(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2),RIGHT(A1,2),0)
```

Or you can use below formula for 24 hours format.

```
=TEXT(TIME(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2),RIGHT(A1,2),0), "hh:mm")
```

If you need `AM/PM` then use

```
=TEXT(TIME(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2),RIGHT(A1,2),0), "hh:mm AM/PM")
```

[image]